# Mock resource within Abstract Class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, abstract-class, powermock

I am trying to test a method within an Abstract Class that uses a resource using Mockito. How do I wire up the Abstract Class method under test to mock the resource?

Here's my abstract class

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass{
@Resource
protected MyResouce resouceWantingToMock;
```

Here's my test class

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyAbstractClass.class)
public class MyAbstractClassTest{

    @Mock
    private MyResouce myResouce;

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        when(resourceWantingToMock.someMethod(anyString())).thenReturn(x)
        MyAbstractClass myAbstractClass = mock(MyAbstractClass.class, CALLS_REAL_METHODS)
        myAbstractClass.callSomeMethod() //*** Within this method the resouce method needs to be mocked
    }
```

Comment: Two questions:  why are you testing the abstract class as opposed to its downstream consumers (considering you'd have to create an instance of it either through mocks or as a dummy class to test it anyway), and where are you injecting the actual mock into?  The last remark indicates that you're missing an `@InjectMocks` call somewhere.

Comment: 1) I don't need to test the class, just the method and mock the Resouce used in the method. 2) That's the problem I don't know how to inject the mock (defined as a Resouce within the Abstract Class) when the Astract Method is being called. I've tried using @InjectMocks for the Resouce within the test class.

Comment: The problem is you won't be able to test that method without creating an instance of that class, and the only way to create an instance of that is to either mock it or to use its downstream consumer.  It's tough to see what you'd be accomplishing in that context.